# Pass random variable to addClass

Tags: jquery, addclass

Just want to generate a random number and then add it as a class to an existing div.

But can't get the variable to be recognised by addClass.

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("#button_text").mouseenter(function() {
        var randomNum = Math.Round(Math.random()*3);
        $("#buttons").addClass(randomNum);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $("#buttons").removeClass(randomNum)
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="buttons">
</div>
```

Any help much appreciated.

---

Thanks for all the help.

Final solution was...

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("#button_text").mouseenter(function() {
        randomNum = 'rand' + Math.round(Math.random()*2);
        $("#buttons").addClass(randomNum);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $("#buttons").removeClass(randomNum)
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="buttons">
</div>
<p>Insert intro sentence here.</p>
<div id="button_text">
  <p>Insert text here that will display the random button background when moused over</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#button_text
{
    display: block;
}
#buttons
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 145px;
    left: 370px;
    z-index: -999;
}
#buttons.rand0
{
    background: url(/hover_buttons.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
#buttons.rand1
{
    background: url(/hover_buttons.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -230px;
}
#buttons.rand2
{
    background: url(/hover_buttons.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -440px;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML doesn't show much. Can you confirm that there is an element with `id="button_text"` somewhere in there?

Comment: It works with `round` and not `Round`:

    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random()*3);

Comment: Guys - thankyou for all your help. What I needed to achieve was to have a div show a different random background every time another div was moused over. So what I set up was a div with id "buttons" which had a background image that had four tiles on it stacked vertically. Then by adding a css class definition for each of the three random classes generated from the script I could specify different background postions for each and thereby display a random image in this div when triggered by the mouseover on the other div "buttons_text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a scoping issue in play here. Make sure your random reference is accessible by both methods. Below I'm declaring my variable outside of my methods, changing its value from the `$.mouseenter()` method and then accessing it again from the `$.mouseleave()` method.

In my example I'm merely setting the text of an element, and then incrementing the text. You can adapt this to your needs by changing the two calls to `$.text()` to `$.addClass()` and `$.removeClass()` respectively.

Note also that it's not advised to use numbers as class names. Perhaps you should prefix the values.

```
var ranNum;

$("#hello")
  .mouseenter(function(){
   ranNum = Math.round(Math.random()*50);
    $(this).text(ranNum);
  })
  .mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).text(ranNum+1); 
  });
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/icuwav/edit

Comment: Thanks - by initially defining the var outside the methods and also fixing the issue with the capital R in round it got me most of the way!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. Scoping - The variable randomNum does not exist when the mouseout method is called so your classes are only added.
2. Even if you make it into a global variable, this won't solve your problem if you use this code multiple times (this might not be the case since you seem to be using IDs, but just in case.)
3. It's `Math.round` and not `Math.Round`
4. Classes shouldn't be composed of just a number

I've use the jQuery data api to store the random classname so you can retrieve it later. Here's a fiddle of what you're trying to achieve : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/339c5/

```
$("#button_text").mouseenter(function() {
    var randClass = 'randomClass' + Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
    $("#buttons").addClass(randClass);
    $("#buttons").data('randClassValue', randClass);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    var randClass = $("#buttons").data('randClassValue');
    $("#buttons").removeClass(randClass)
});

<p id='button_text'>
    <a id='buttons'>Buttons</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks - I used your method of combining the random number with a prefix to get the class to show up, as you highlighted in point 4, classes can;t be just a number.

Answer (score 1):

try converting it to a string before adding it as a class.

edit: also, as others have mentions `Math.Round` needs to be `Math.round`

Answer (score 0):

Math.Round isn't a method in javascript. However; Math.round *is*.

```
$(function() {
    $("#button_text").hover(function() {
        var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random()*3);
        $("#buttons").addClass(randomNum);
    }, function() {
        $("#buttons").removeClass(randomNum)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your randomNum is declared inside your mouseenter function with 'var' - it isn't visible to mouseleave().

You may also run into problems if your class names don't start with a letter - although numbers may "just work" I don't think they are valid class identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an integer value use Math.ceil

```
var randomNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
```

Comment: Math.round also returns an integer value.